# [wsgi:error]:No module named mysite.settings

Tags: django, python-2.7, wamp, web-deployment, wampserver

I have deployed Django app in Wamp server which was working fine. Unfortunately after running pip install Wamp server stopped serving Django applicaiton and throwing below error

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=26240): Target WSGI script 'D:/testdeployment/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=26240): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'D:/testdeployment/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:/testdeployment/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
 application = get_wsgi_application()
 File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.9.4-py2.7.egg\\django\\core\\wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
 django.setup()
 File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.9.4-py2.7.egg\\django\\__init__.py", line 17, in setup
 configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
 File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.9.4-py2.7.egg\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
 self._setup(name)
 File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.9.4-py2.7.egg\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
 self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
 File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.9.4-py2.7.egg\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
       mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
     File "C:\\Python27\\Lib\\importlib\\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
       __import__(name)
   ImportError: No module named mysite.settings
```

WSGI.PY

```
  import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Wamp configuration:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / "D:/testdeployment/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "D:/testdeployment/mysite/mysite/"


<Directory "D:/testdeployment/mysite/mysite/">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>



<Directory "D:/testdeployment/mysite/mysite/">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
</Directory>
```

Please let me know what is the issue here

Comment: Problem has been solved here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210686/importerror-no-module-named-mysite-settings-django/36211423)

Comment: Problem has been solved here. It worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210686/importerror-no-module-named-mysite-settings-django/36211423

Answer (score 0):

The python path should be the outer `mysite` directory (the one containing `manage.py`), not the inner `mysite` directory (the one containing `settings.py` and `wsgi.py`).

```
WSGIPythonPath "D:/testdeployment/mysite/"
```

See the Django docs for [deploying with Apache and mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#basic-configuration) for more info.

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue, I can't help with that.

Comment: Actually when point to simple empty project I am able to see default Django page, however when I point real project nothing is loading

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but when i looked the locations of files through file explorer , i got to know that i have the files placed inaccurately, like the django searchers for mysite.settings but i have folder called mysite and in that folder i have my mysite file, so the django couldn't find my file. try looking at the file arrangement.